# Shorten Search String to get around character limitations

Tags: search, query, managed-property

We are trying to use the standard sharepoint search alerts and are currently being limited by some character limitations. I am wondering if there is a way to shorten our search strings...

For example:

We are trying to search based on managed properties...

```
(LoanID:13224 OR LoanID:47654)
```

Is there a way I can eliminate the need to retype 'LoanID:' repeatedly to shoren the overall string?

Answer (score 1):

You can review the list of search operators in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx) but there isn't one that will let you pass multiple values for one property. You can however remove the OR to save some space.

> When you use multiple instances of the same property restriction,
>   matches are based on the union of the property restrictions in the KQL
>   query. Matches would include content items authored by John Smith or
>   Jane Smith, as follows:
>
> author:"John Smith" author:"Jane Smith"
>
> This functionally is the same as using the OR Boolean operator, as follows:
>
> author:"John Smith" OR author:"Jane Smith"